Why is the request body of UnityWebRequest empty?
I used following code to send a POST request:
string jsonUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/backend/login";
string data = "{\"userName\":\"" + playerEmail + "\", \"password\":\""+playerPassword + "\"}";
Debug.Log(data);
var request = new UnityWebRequest(jsonUrl, "POST");
byte[] bodyRaw = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(data);
request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/json";
yield return request.SendWebRequest();

The server receives an empty request body. Following code in python works:
import requests
data={'userName':'admin','password':'admin'}
print(requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/backend/login',data=data).text)

Server side code:
@PostMapping("/backend/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> login(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestBody) {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(requestBody);
        if (userService.selectCountByNameAndPassword(requestBody.get("userName"), requestBody.get("password")) > 0) {
            result.put("type", "1");
            result.put("message", "success");
        } else {
            result.put("type", "0");
            result.put("message", "wrong username or password");
        }
        return result;
    }

Unity version: 2022.3.17f1c1
I expect the server to receive the full request body.

From where do you execute this? Do you try this in the editor or in a build? When it's in a build, what kind of build? WebGL by any chance? If so, is your WebGL content also hosted on 127.0.0.1? If not you will run into CORS issues that need to be resolved on the server with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Keep in mind that http and https can also cause additional problems. What response code does the request return?

where do you check that the result was successful?
